# IPSec VPN client connection fails

Tags: centos, vpn, ipsec

#### My router VPN setting for my user:

[image: fritz]

- The router supports:  **IPSec** with **ESP, IKEv1**
- Does **NOT** support: **Authentification Header, AH** and **Perfect Forward Security, PFS**

#### Linux Centos 8

- Secret: sabf6...
- Password: Not written

[image]

[image]

##### Some checks

- `ipsec` service is enabled and running
- `ipsec verify` is all green:

[image]

#### Wireshark screenshot:

[image: wireshark]

[image]

#### What do I miss? I've never used IPSec, always OpenVPN.

Comment: IPsec is a nightmare to get right. You're going to need to provide the full configuration in both sides (obfuscate passwords usernames and endpoints, but please make sure you are consistent so that the same password is obfuscated with the same replacement, etc.) No guarantees that the two sides are capable of taking to reach other, either.

Comment: Updated. It doesn't seem to be so complicated tho.